# Default packages not found in R (Ubuntu)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, package

i'm new with R and i'm having some problems in making it work properly.

When I type "R" in my terminal (linux Ubuntu) I get the following warning:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

which I think are the cause of many other problems like not being able to install other packages.

I read a lot of similar question but they were very old and I have not been able to adapt them to my case.
Anyway, I think that the problem is something related to the default packeges folders.

I cannot install Rstudio because it's a machine with only terminal access.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Packages need to be found on the search path specified by `.libPaths()`. Having said that, it's odd that you are missing **stats** and **utils** but not **graphics**, etc.

Comment: How exactly was R installed on that machine? What R version is it?

Comment: I installed R following the official instuction [here](https://cran.r-project.org/), the vesion is 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem:

apparently during the loading of R, some bash script uses the `which` command to get the full path of something. Now, I don't know why, on my linux installation the `which` command was named `which.debianutils` and the executable `/bin/which` was not present. I solved with `sudo apt reinstall debianutils`.

Answer (score 1):

if you go to https://cran.r-project.org/ and click on "download R for unix" , then select Ubuntu,  you'll find a page full of info on how properly to install R and R packages from a terminal session.

However, if you somehow managed to destroy your Ubuntu install such that there  is **no Desktop at all** and you can't even run a web browser, then you may have bigger problems.

Comment: I followed the instruction in that site in order to install R, including the CRAN packages.
There is no desktop because I only have ssh access.